# How to enable the GPS setting automatic

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enable GPS programatically like Tasker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker)

Anybody know how to enable the GPS setting automatic? Seems the 
"Toggle Settings" app can handle it, but I want to force open in my app sdk 2.1.
some people said

```
 "Method m =locationManager.getClass().getMethod("updateProviders", new Class[] {});
                m.setAccessible(true);
                m.invoke(locationManager, new Object[]{});"
```

but  in sdk2.1  locationManager class donot have updateProviders.
couled you give me some directions or code?

Please help me if you have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinary SDK applications cannot change the GPS enabled state. Only those signed by the firmware signing key can do this, via `Settings.Secure`.

Comment: Don't reflect cannot use?  i want to use reflect,

Comment: @pengwang: Reflection cannot help, and if it does, it is a security flaw in Android that needs to be fixed. If the user disables GPS, please abide by that user's wishes.

Comment: and how can they change it ? do you have some code ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales: There are methods on `Settings.Secure` for changing the settings: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html